# How to create table inside dynamically created database in sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am working on a rest api using nodejs, express and sequelize orm. The api i am creating is for a android application which is based on SAAS platform. Therefore, I need to create separate database for each user of my application. There will be a master database which will be used to identify the database credential for each user while logging in. The master database will be connected by default and in each api call, in each route i need to connect/create the user specific database including the tables.

/* This is my db.js file for master database connection using sequelize. */

```
require('dotenv').config();
const sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = new sequelize('master_db', process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASS, {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    operatorAliases: false,

    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    }
});
```

/* This is a model Demo.js */

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../../db');

const Demo_table = db.define('demo_table', {
    // attributes
    demo_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    demo_name: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
    }
}, {
    // options
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
});

module.exports = Demo_table;
```

/* This demo_route.js file in route folder*/

```
"use strict";
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const checkAuth = require('../middleware/auth');

//load controllers
const DemoController = require('../controllers/demo_member');

router.post('/demo_activity', checkAuth, DemoController.demo_activity);

module.exports = router;
```

/* This is the controller file demo_member.js*/

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

//load models
const Demo = require('../models/Demo');

exports.create_demo_team = (req, res) => {
   /* here i need to create the database of the user who is calling this api if the database(with tables) is not created else need to connect with the existing user's database and perform CRUD*/
}
```

I am expecting with the solution which will fulfil my requirement at the earliest. where i can create database dynamically, then create table and  connect with it to perform CRUD.

Comment: I also have same issue, did you get the solution for this case . please share the solution if  u found one